# SSIS Check date format with conditional split

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis

I have a flat file that with a "date" column. The problem is that date could come in as

`01-Jan-16` or

```
01Jan2016
```

If I run this in a derived column

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(bene_dob,1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(bene_dob,3,3) + "-" + SUBSTRING(bene_dob,7,4))
```

it handles the second date fine, but really screws up the first date.

I'm trying to deal with this thru a conditional split, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

How do I verify that date format in a conditional split?

Or if you have an alternative suggestion, I'm open to ideas.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the dashes with an empty string before the derived column so that all rows will have the same format (01Jan2016).   You'll also need to add the first 2 digits of the year if they are missing.

Or if you really want to use a conditional split, just test for the presence of the hyphen character and split based on whether it is in the string or not.

Comment: Thanks this is easiest approach so far.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty method would be to *normalize* the date column, so strip it of the unwanted characters ('-' in this case) and then apply your derived column expression like so:

```
(DT_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(bene_dob, "-", ""),1,2) + "-" + SUBSTRING(REPLACE(bene_dob, "-", ""),3,3) + "-" + SUBSTRING(REPLACE(bene_dob, "-", ""),7,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would get all the date formats into the same format before further processing, can either do this via sql or a Data Conversion in ssis.